# Chrome copies address bar contents as a link

Tags: google-chrome, lync

When I copy URL of current page from address bar Chrome doesn't copy it as a plain text. As a result when I have to send it on Microsoft Lync, the link is pasted twice. Below is the screen grab of Lync window:

[image]

Here I had copied the link of superuser.com and pasted it in Lync window, it pasted twice. If the same is done inside a notepad it copies the link as a plain text.

**Update:**

1. I don't get option 'Paste As Plain Text' inside Microsoft Lync when I right click: Here is a snapshot:
   [image]

Comment: Can you right click and "Paste as Plain Text" on Lync?

Comment: No. I don't get that option in the right click menu. I get only option to Paste.

Comment: There are programs that will let you paste things as plain text, but for the past decade or two, whenever I need to do this, I always just press `Win+R` to open the *Run* dialog, then I paste it there and copy it back to the clipboard because it will strip all formatting.

Comment: Yes, that is the process I follow right now. Or paste it in the window and remove the duplicate part. This is tedious job